# Implicit jsonFormat for case class with varargs

Tags: scala, akka, spray, spray-json

I have a case class containing varargs, with an implicit jsonFormat as follows:

```
import spray.json._
case class Colors(name: String*)
object MyJsonProtocol extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat1(Colors)
}
import MyJsonProtocol._
Colors("CadetBlue").toJson
```

It raises an error:

```
error: type mismatch;
found   : Color2.type
required: Seq[String] => Color2
Note: implicit value colorFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
      implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat1(Color2)
                                            ^
```

I have also tried:

```
implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat1(Colors.apply)
```

which caused a different (runtime!) exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot automatically determine case class field names and order for 'Colors', please use the 'jsonFormat' overload with explicit field name specification
```

The following:

```
implicit val colorFormat = jsonFormat(Colors, "name")
```

raises the former error

It is even possible to define implicit jsonFormat for case class with varargs?

Comment: Have you already considered using a Seq[String] instead?

Comment: Use `List[String]` instead of varargs, or make your own unmarshaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work perfectly, probably you have some ambiguity in implicits. This works perfectly:

```
import spray.json._, DefaultJsonProtocol._

case class Test(param: String*)
object Test {
  implicit val testFormat = jsonFormat1(Test.apply)
}
```

Like a best practice advice, don't use Protocol pattern, it leads to large implicit errors in big project, always define implicits in your companion object (of cause there are exception cases). Another point avoid inheritance, it's not really needed.

Scala `*` pattern is just a sugar for `Seq` type constructor, so it should find `seqFormat` (un)marshaller for this cases.

**Update**

It doesn't work because Spray uses `ClassManifest` to extract field names from the `copy` function, but the compiler doesn't generate this function for case classes with varargs in constructor:

```
case class Test(params: String*)
def man[A: ClassManifest] = implicitly[ClassManifest[A]]
man[Test].erasure.getDeclaredMethods.filter(_.getName.contains("copy"))
res4: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array()

scala> case class Test(param: String)
defined class Test

scala> man[Test].erasure.getDeclaredMethods.filter(_.getName.contains("copy"))
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
res5: Array[java.lang.reflect.Method] = Array(public Test Test.copy(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String Test.copy$default$1())
```

So you need to provide the field name manually. BTW i didn't know this before

Comment: Tried in the scala console: `error: value apply is not a member of object Test` \n `Note: implicit value testFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type`

Comment: @mirelon you need to switch to "`:paste`" mode then eval it

Comment: Now there is an error: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot automatically determine case class field names and order for 'Test', please use the 'jsonFormat' overload with explicit field name specification` and `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Case class Test declares additional fields` (Note I added a line with `Test("a","b").toJson` to your code)

Comment: @mirelon change to `jsonFormat(Test.apply _, "param")`

Comment: Thanks, now it works, but I don't understand why exactly. Could you edit the answer with an explanation?

Answer (score 12):

I also experienced this exception, however in my case it was due to a 'val' definition within the case class (not as passed argument).

**Problematic** case class:

```
case class Color(name: String) {
  val code: Int = ...
}
```

**Working** case class:

```
case class Color(name: String) {
  def code: Int = ...
}
```

Which is kind of misfortunate as, now the 'code' will be computed on each call.

(Used Akka Http Version - 10.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to define your case class with `name: List[String]` and create companion object with custom apply function. You are still able to create objects like `Colors("blue", "green")`.

```
case class Colors(name: List[String])

object Colors {
  def apply(name: String*): Colors = new Colors(name.toList)
  def apply(names: List[String]): Colors = new Colors(names)
}


Colors("blue", "green")
```

Comment: When I add `implicit val colorsFormat = jsonFormat1(Colors.apply)` then there is an error `ambiguous reference to overloaded definition` and when I use `implicit val colorsFormat = jsonFormat1(Colors)` then the error is `type mismatch;
 found   : Colors.type
 required: ? => ?`